# PImpl idiom using std::unique_pointer with the implementation class in a seperate source file

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, pimpl-idiom

I am writing a simple library to handle window creation across different platforms. To abstract away the platform specific code i want to use the PImpl idiom with a std::unique_ptr and provide a platform specific private implementation with a factory function. This is what i currently have:

**Window.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class Window
{
public:    
    Window();
    ~Window();    
private:    
    class WindowImpl;    
    std::unique_ptr<WindowImpl> impl;
};
```

**Window.cpp:**

```
#include "Window.h"
#include "WindowImpl.h"

Window::Window() : impl(WindowImpl::create()) {}    
Window::~Window() = default;
```

**WindowImpl.h:**

```
#include "Window.h"
#include <memory>

class Window::WindowImpl
{
public:    
    static std::unique_ptr<WindowImpl> create();
};
```

**WindowImpl.cpp:**

```
#include "WindowImpl.h"

std::unique_ptr<Window::WindowImpl> Window::WindowImpl::create()
{
    // the plan is to return the platform specific WindowImpl implementation here
    return std::make_unique<Window::WindowImpl>();
}
```

This seems to do what i want. My Problem ist that i currently have to specify "*Window::*" in front of basicly everything in WindowImpl.cpp. Since Window is a class and not a namespace "using Window" doesn't work. The examples i found about this topic all have their full Impl class definition inside the source file of their class using it and thus didn't have this problem. But i need to have WindowImpl in a seperate header if i want to derive the platform specific implemetations from it.

Is there a way to keep WindowImpl in its own header/source file and get rid of that verbosity?

Comment: Why not simply make a namespace that includes `WindowImpl` and put it outside of class `Window`? Also the way it is written you most surely cannot  have an instance `Window` without including "WindowImpl.h". It will scream for not finding destructor of `WindowImpl`.

Comment: @ALX23z Yes you can instanciate it without including WindowImpl.h. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: Because without including "WindowImpl.h" compiler won't know how to delete it. Hmm... if destructor for `WindowImpl` is called only in Window.cpp then it will be fine.

Comment: @ALX23z The compiler need's to know how to delete within the destructor of Window and WindowImpl is a complete type there. I tested it, it definetly works with only including  Window.h.

Comment: But you realize that now you have to implement move assignment/ctor for `Window` inside Window.cpp which will make it slow and non-inlinable?

Comment: @ALX23z Or just make sure they're deleted instead of implicitly declared.

Comment: Note the full name shouldn't be necessary anywhere after the declarator of the definition: `auto Window::WindowImpl::create() -> std::unique_ptr<WindowImpl> { return std::make_unique<WindowImpl>(); }`

Comment: @aschepler it is pretty bad to have non-movable class that has zero reasons to be non-movable - as it's implementation is already hidden behind a dynamic allocation.

Comment: @ALX23z Your suggestion of using a namespace out of Window suffers from the same problem of having to declare the constructor of Window inside of Window.cpp. What would be a better way to implement PImpl idiom then?

Comment: @Eric use `std::unique_ptr` with custom destructor - an empty class that that implements call to delete inside the .cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use type-aliasing, however, that will require you to make the nested class public, which may defeat the use of the PImpl idiom:

```
using WImpl = typename Window::WindowImpl;

std::unique_ptr<WImpl> WImpl::create(){
    //implementation goes here
}
```

Edit:

Other than that, you may have to use macros to remove the verbosity:

```
#define WIMPL Window::WindowImpl;

std::unique_ptr<WIMPL> WIMPL::create(){
    //implementation goes here
}
```

Comment: That results in the compiler error "cannot access private class declared in class 'window'" using the latest version of msvc.

Comment: @Eric Yes, you're correct, I forgot about that. I've edited the post with another possible solution.